# Как програмно менять CSS стили в GWT-приложении?

Tags: gwt, java, css

Меняю стиль элемента формы вот так:

```
label1.setStyleName(".my-label_style1");
```

на форме это не отражается, как правильно делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку исправил, имя стиля не правильно указывал, правильный вариант без точки:

```
label1.setStyleName("my-label_style1");
```